# I keep getting the "TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "float") to str" error

Tags: python

```
meal = float(input("Enter the price of the meal:\n"))
if meal>4.00:
    tax = meal * 1.13
    round(tax, 2)
    total = tax + meal
    print("Subtotal: $" + meal + "\n" + "Total Taxes: $" + tax + "\n" + "Total: $" + total)
```

I am trying to do an assignment for school, and when I output this code with addition symbols, it produces this error, but if I were to use commas, it would print with spaces. How can I fix this?

Comment: `tax` is a numeric value and cannot be concatenated as a string. Perhaps try `str(tax)`.  Same goes for `meal` and  `total`.  Better yet, use f-strings [as mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67577251/6340496), it’s much cleaner code.

Comment: You need to convert the numbers to strings using `str(meal)` and `str(tax)`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Cast your values to str

```
print("Subtotal: $" + str(meal) + "\n" + "Total Taxes: $" + str(tax) + "\n" + "Total: $" + str(total))
```

or use f-string:

```
print(f"Subtotal: ${meal}\nTotal Taxes: ${tax}\nTotal: ${total}")
```

Answer (score -1):

`meal`, `tax` and `total` are floats so you need to use [str()](https://docs.python.org/fr/2.7/library/functions.html#str).

```
meal = float(input("Enter the price of the meal:\n"))
if meal>4.00:
    tax = meal * 1.13
    round(tax, 2)
    total = tax + meal
    print("Subtotal: $" + str(meal) + "\n" + "Total Taxes: $" + str(tax) + "\n" + "Total: $" + str(total))
```